# redirect wrong dir request

Tags: .htaccess

In the last days the bingbot is trying to access pages that don't exist and I didn't get up to now to identify the origin of these links. Before the original and valid url it is increasing a random dir, example:

```
GET /ToWLQ/my-valid-url-here-4416.html HTTP/1.1" 404 2608 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"

My correct url is:
/my-valid-url-here-4416.html
```

The string /XuRT/ and the pages are frequently changed.

I would like to redirect through the htaccess to avoid so many mistakes.

```
from: /ToWLQ/my-valid-url-here-4416.html  
to: /my-valid-url-here-4416.html
```

Thank you

Vera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer here depends on whether you can effectively generalize the pattern that the bingbot prefixes your pages with, as well as the pattern of your pages. Based on the information you provide in the question, a rule like this in your .htaccess will work:

```
RewriteRule ^[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]+/(.*) $1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

This assumes that the first letter will be uppercase, the second lowercase, and the rest uppercase, followed by a slash then your real page.

**EDIT**: New rewrite rule based on more information:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT}  (msnbot|bingbot)
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{5}/)+(.*) $2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  
To complicate the letters can vary between capital letters and lower cases.  
See the examples collected in the log today.  

    /XUMKT/,
    /MLUeV/,  
    /PmdfY/KbRkX/,  
    /NPPPY/WiTfQ/,  
    /ToNlT/XjcXZ/MTQpX/,  
    /UjSOV/RQmmL/PoYVU/YSkTS/  
  
All of the accesses are from bingbot. Would it be possible to apply this redirect just for the requests from Bing bot?

Comment: Hi - will update the rule in a bit after checking it, and also after seeing if I can restrict it only for bingbot.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am testing and I will inform the result soon.

Comment: Hmm can you take a look into your server access logs and see what user-agent string the bots are identifying themselves with?

Comment: log:65.52.110.34 - - [25/May/2012:00:42:49 -0300] "GET /WpUeS/my-correct-url-here-4922.html HTTP/1.1" 404 1786 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)"

Comment: Ah in that case, change the `Bingbot` in my earlier rule to `bingbot`. Just edit the rule in the **EDIT** section.

Comment: Thank you for your help and interest, but it still didn't work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  
Finally it worked:  
"RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} bingbot    
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{5}/)+(.*) $2 [L,R=301,QSA]"